# Pass arguments in MFC-single-document

Tags: c++, mfc

I am doing a small drawing tool with MFC.

Firstly, I create a dialog to select one shape from four shapes(rectangle, line, circle, ellipse), and draw it.

Second, I create a modeless dialog to display the coordinates of the shape(`startpoint.x`, `startpoint.y`, `width`, `height`).

Coordinate dialog as below:

[image]

Finally, I create a dialog to choose other parameters. When clicking OK button, coordinates of the shape will pass to `void CPropertyDlg::OnBnClickedOk()`. But I found all the coordinates are zero, is that because the dialog and coordinates are instant? Once closing the dialog, the coordinates are set zero automatically?

Code to get coordinates in `DrawToolView.cpp` as below:

```
void CDrawToolView::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{

    m_startRect=FALSE;
    ::ClipCursor(NULL);  
    CClientDC dc(this);  
    dc.SelectStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);  
    dc.Rectangle(CRect(m_startPoint,m_OldPoint));    // draw rectangle
    dc.Rectangle(CRect(m_startPoint,point));  
}
```

Code to pass coordinates to `void CPropertyDlg::OnBnClickedOk()` as below:

```
void CPropertyDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    UpdateData(); 
    CDrawToolView coordinate; 
    origin_x = coordinate.m_startPoint.x;
    origin_y = coordinate.m_startPoint.y;
    width = coordinate.m_OldPoint.x-coordinate.m_startPoint.x;
    height = coordinate.m_OldPoint.y-coordinate.m_startPoint.y;;
    OnOK();
}
```

Could some one help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a dialog dervived from `CDialog` or CDialogEx`, you would normally declare member variables which are connected to the controls in the dialog box -- see MSDN article [Dialog Data Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwz5tb1x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Once you call `UpdateData()`, the values from the connected controls are available in the dialog member variables. In your calling function, you would do something like

```
CPropertyDlg dlg;
dlg.m_origin_x = m_startPoint.x;
dlg.m_origin_y = m_startPoint.y;
dlg.m_width = coordinate.m_OldPoint.x-coordinate.m_startPoint.x;
dlg.m_height = coordinate.m_OldPoint.y-coordinate.m_startPoint.y;
if (dlg.DoModal == IDOK)
{   m_startPoint.x = dlg.m_origin_x;
    m_startPoint.y = dlg.m_origin_y;
    coordinate.m_OldPoint.x = m_startPoint.x + dlg.m_width;
    coordinate.m_OldPoint.y = m_startPoint.y + dlg.m_height;
    // take action
}
```